# Consuming web services in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

I am testing web services in .NET for the first time. I am almost there, but I can't seem to consume the web service. I know this post is similar to about 5-6 other posts on this site, but I have reviewed them, and still can't get the syntax correct.

So far, I have:
-Create a simple web service that creates a directory
-Worked in development environment, but took some trouble shooting to get to work on live server
-I can pull up the "automagically" generated .NET we service page.
-Added web service reference - can now see the reference in my solution explorer and in intellisense.

Update:
Here is a link to the webservice itself:
http://67.78.188.50/Jservices/Service1.asmx

The web service accepts a string (name of directory e.g /test/directory). However, when I enter the name of the Web Reference (ServiceReference1) - I don't get the methods I expect...

Here are my options with the ServiceReference1 Object...

```
ServiceReference1.makeDirRequest
ServiceReference1.makeDirRequestBody
ServiceReference1.makeDirResponse
ServiceReference1.makeDirResponseBody
ServiceReference1.Service1Soap
ServiceReference1.Service1SoapChannel
ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient
```

Comment: If you don't have anything nice to say, John Saunders, don't say anything at all :)

Comment: If you have WebMethods exposed in your service, you could invoke them. Do you have any methods on your service with the [WebMethod()] attribute?

Comment: Yes, makeDir is the exposed web method using that attribute. It's the syntax for "Invoke" that I can't seem to get. What would the invoke statement look like?

Comment: so from what you are saying it should be createDir.makeDir(params...)

Comment: @cinqoTimo: I don't even remember what I said. It must have been something like, have you looked at the basic documentation about consuming web services, and did you know you should be using WCF  unless you have no other choice? I have a blog post showing how to consume a web service, but it's on johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com, and I can't access that from work, so you'll have to look for it.

Comment: You left out - "Are you stupid? - Can you read?" :) - I haven't worked with WCF before, but I'll be happy to give it a whirl if it is the correct path. As far as basic documentation - I've found several posts that all seem like "good" docs, all use different methods, none of which were working out for me.

Comment: Can you get any sample services to work?

Comment: @cinqoTimo: SO has changed so that if you had put "@John Saunders" in your comment, I'd have been informed immediately. I hope I gave a URL when I asked if you could read. What URL did I give?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass, you haven't posted enough code to see what you have done

I would strongly recommend that your use WCF

Given your sample names proved, you need

```
Dim service As New ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient
service.makeDir("some val")
```

Download one of the many samples on the web (plenty on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/GettingStartedWithWCF.aspx)) and get the sample working first. If you cant get that to go then something else is wrong with you Windows installation

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that `makeDirRequest` is the service - that sounds like a *message*. Look for another type in that namespace (maybe ending in "service" or "client" if you are lucky, but ultimately named based on what you typed when using "add web reference" etc), that inherits from `WebService`.

*This* should have your *service* method(s) as  public methods.

---

Having seen the service, I *expect* the problem is that you are adding a *service-reference* (WCF / 3.0) rather than a *web-reference* (2.0). If you are targetting 3.0 / 3.5, you can add a *web-reference* by using the "Advanced..." => "Add Web Reference" option 
(in the "Add Service Reference" dialog). Then you can use (where `WebReference` is whatever you named it when adding the reference):

```
Using client As WebReference.Service1 = New WebReference.Service1
    Dim foo As String = "foo"
    client.makeDir(foo)
End Using
```

If you instead use a *WCF service-reference*, then the name tends to include the "Soap" overhead (where `ServiceReference1` is whatever you named it when adding the reference):

```
Using client As ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient = New ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient
    Dim foo As String = "foo"
    client.makeDir(foo)
End Using
```

Either way, it should work the same.

Comment: Thanks Marc - I added more info on what I'm seeing. It is somehow different than all the articles people are posting, not sure why...

Comment: Especially the part >> you can add a web-reference by using the "Advanced..." => "Add Web Reference" option << is important. I had struggled  with that when I used a web service for the first time in a Win Forms application. A lot of tutorials talk about "adding a reference", but the point is to add a web reference.

Answer (score 2):

Consume a Web service in a .NET app

<del>http://articles.techrepublic.com/5100-10878_11-5768122.html</del>

Creating and Consuming Web Services - OS, Software & Networking by ...

http://www.extremetech.com/article2/0,2845,11511,00.asp

Consuming Web Services from a Win Forms Application - CodeProject

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/cpwebserviceconsumer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/) and see if it helps you. The example is in C#, but you should find it easy to translate.

Comment: @John Saunders - Thanks John, I did find your article and it was good for a beginner. I need to learn more about WCF. I know it is going to be the MS preferred platform for web services, but I don't understand the mechanics of it. This is a very simple service, so I'm not going to port it to WCF because it is already working, but I will use WCF moving forward. Thanks..

Comment: @cinqoTimo: I'm glad it helped. BTW, it's not "going to be" the MS preferred platform. It has been the preferred platform for over three years. ASMX web services are now considered "legacy technology", and should not be used for new development.