# how to create a loop in vb.net which reads from sql database and sends it to webservice

Tags: sql, vb.net, web-services, loops

i want to write a loop which reads a row from sql data table, take the attributes and save it to variables. the variables are parameters for a webservice. i have 103 columns but most time not all are used, i only want to get out the attributes which are used. the other variables shall stay at there initialized value.

Anybody knows a fast way to do it? a code example would be cool, but a hint were also good enough for the beginning.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't exactly demonstrated what you've already tried so I'm not inclined to give you a completely functioning solution however the following snippets and links might prove useful:

**Traversing SQL Results**

There are obviously many ways of doing this I tend to use a `SqlDataReader`

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionStringName").ConnectionString)
    Using command As New SqlCommand("storedProcedureName", connection)
        command.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        '** Add Parameters if required **'
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("parameterName", parameterValue)
        connection.Open()
        Using dataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                While dataReader.Read
                    '** Put code here for interacting with the web service **'
                End While
        End Using
        connection.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Getting the data from the columns is actually quite easy, you can access them explicitly by column name or by index and getting ordinal to see what it's value is. When a column returns `DBNull`, determined using a call such as `IsDBNull(columnValue)`, then the value has not been populated in the database. Given the number of columns you are dealing with I would recommend using the [SqlDataReader.Item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y64yaah2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the value and [SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for getting the name of the column.

**Interacting with a Web Service**

A quick google (other search engines are available) will give you plenty of examples on how to consume a web service in `VB.NET`. Here's a few of the examples I think you should consider looking at for this part:

1. [**Code Project:** Using a Web Service in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3783/Using-a-Web-Service-in-VB-NET)
2. [**Microsoft:** How to access a Web service in a Windows-based application by using Visual Basic 2005 or Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818364)
3. [**Stack Overflow:** Consuming Web Services in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297419/consuming-web-services-in-vb-net)

The above examples will be much more eloquent in their examples and will give you a better understanding than I can in a small answer box so I am not going to write code snippets for this part.

Comment: well, i minimized the problem, so that i only want to get a datarow from sql database into an array. it prefer to use the options i have like dataset, datatable, etc.. befor using sql statements.. because the whole code before this problem runs without it...